# unable to stat `./mnt' (which I was about to install): Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg

When running:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

on 12.04.3 LTS, kernel 3.2.0-35-virtual

I get:

```
Preparing to replace base-files 6.5ubuntu6.6 (using .../base-files_6.5ubuntu6.7_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement base-files ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/base-files_6.5ubuntu6.7_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to stat `./mnt' (which I was about to install): Transport endpoint is not connected
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for install-info ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/base-files_6.5ubuntu6.7_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Output of `df -ha` :

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       99G  9.1G   85G  10% /
none               0     0     0    - /proc
sysfs              0     0     0    - /sys
none               0     0     0    - /sys/fs/fuse/connections
none               0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/debug
none               0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/security
udev            819M   12K  819M   1% /dev
devpts             0     0     0    - /dev/pts
tmpfs           331M  192K  331M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            827M     0  827M   0% /run/shm
cgroup          827M     0  827M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/memory
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/devices
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event
```

Output of `mount` :

```
/dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw)
none on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,relatime,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,relatime,cpuset,clone_children)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu type cgroup (rw,relatime,cpu,clone_children)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct type cgroup (rw,relatime,cpuacct,clone_children)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,relatime,memory,clone_children)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,relatime,devices,clone_children)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,relatime,freezer,clone_children)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,relatime,blkio,clone_children)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,relatime,perf_event,clone_children)
```

I have tried solutions found here such as:

```
apt-get clean

dpkg --configure -a

dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/base-files_6.5ubuntu6.7_amd64.deb

rm /var/cache/apt/archives/base-files_6.5ubuntu6.7_amd64.deb
```

Also thought I would mention that I am running an LXC container. Anybody know how I can clear this up?

Comment: See the error "Transport endpoint is not connected". Try googling for that. This looks like a filesystem issue. Are you using an non-standard filesystems?

Comment: Do you have anything mounted on `/mnt`? What's the output of `mount`?

Comment: Post the output of `df -ha` in the question, please.

Comment: Details added. I am researching the error more but no solution yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message indicates that you have a non-default filesystem on /mnt that's in a problematic state. The base-files package provides the /mnt directory on the filesystem, so dpkg assumes it should be able to unpack that directory if necessary. You need to unmount /mnt on your system to upgrade base-files.

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/base-files/+bug/1352012 for more info.